# How can I conditionally include PHP files for the homepage only, through functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to `require_once` a php file from the lib folder in my theme, but only in the landing page which is also the blog / post index page.

When I add the `require_once` code to functions.php on its own it works fine, but is executed also on all pages and single posts which I need to prevent.

When I add the following conditional query tags, they seem to be ignored and the file is not included on the homepage.

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  require_once 'lib/example.php';
}
```

What am I missing and what is recommended way to do this?

Note: this must be added to the theme's functions.php file.

Comment: The require_once is done in the functions.php, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code won't work as it is if it is included in the body of functions.php, because it gets loaded before everything is ready for `is_home` or `is_front_page` to work. You need to hook into one of the Wordpress actions that happens after that.

The following code will hook into the `wp` action, where the conditional actions will work:

```
// create a function to do the conditional check and include the files
function include_files_homepage_only() {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        require_once 'lib/example.php';
    }
}

// hook into the wp action to call our function
add_action('wp', 'include_files_homepage_only');
```

Note:

- The front page and home (post index page) are the same in your site
  so you don't need to check if the page is equal to both `is_front_page` and `is_home`. Using both checks could break your expected functionality if you ever changed the front page or posts page in your WP Admin Settings.
- You should use the proper path for the file you are including, e.g.
  use get_stylesheet_directory or get_template_directory as
  appropriate.

**Reference**: [Wordpress Codex for Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

> **Warning**: You can only use conditional query tags after the posts_selection [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) in WordPress (the wp action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace && with ||

```
if (is_front_page() || is_home()) {
    require_once 'lib/example.php';
}
```

Comment: we would assume both those functions checked different things, right? i dont know who down-voted you but i up-voted you back to zero again

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
if ( is_front_page()) {
  require_once 'lib/example.php';
}
```

OR

```
if (is_home() ) {
  require_once 'lib/example.php';
}
```

You don't need both.
[is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)  --- Checks if its the index page of your website.
[is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)  --- Checks if this is the blog page selected in the settings( **This won't work if its not selected in the settings** )

Comment: This doesn´t work from the functions PHP but works e.g. from the index.php. Die I need to hook it somehow in the functions.php? WP doesnt know at this stage, when included in the functions.php, if it is home or frontpage?

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in header.php before `wp_head();`

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lib/example.php' );
}
```